# Expectations of two random variables

Tags: expected-value, covariance

Are the following two statements correct?

$\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}(Y)] = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y),$
and

$\mathbb{E}[X(aY-a\mathbb{E}(Y))] = a\mathbb{E}[XY]-a\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y] = a Cov(X,Y)$,

where $X$ and $Y$ are some (possibly dependent) random variables and $Cov(X,Y)$ stands for the covariance of $X$ and $Y$.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Except there is one right-bracket missing: $\mathbb E[X(aY-a\mathbb E(Y))]$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you! I corrected the mistake.

Comment: You can search for the answers of this kind of common questions, for example, here is [search results](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cmathbb%7BE%7D%5BX%5Cmathbb%7BE%7D(Y)%5D%20%3D%20%5Cmathbb%7BE%7D(X)%5Cmathbb%7BE%7D(Y)%2C%24&p=1) from Approach0.